# How to hide a overlay with Leaflet

Tags: overlay, leaflet

this is a part of my leaflet code :

```js
// Init
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [46.7, 2.5],
    zoom: 6,
    layers: [test, boutiques]
});

L.tileLayer('http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

// overlays
var overlays = {
    "Test": test,
    "Boutiques": boutiques
};
L.control.layers(overlays).addTo(map);
```

I want that a overlay can be displayed one by one (via radio button), the problem is that at loading the "boutiques" overlay is selected but "test" is also displayed.. How to put "test" hidden by default ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just initialize map without `test`:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
  center: [46.7, 2.5],
  zoom: 6,
  layers: [boutiques]
});
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/RXDzC/1/).